# mod_rewrite using QSA,N together

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I wrote a mod_rewrite script that removes non-existent folders from any lookup, but passes the folder names to a .php script in an array. The script works as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3

# Does the current request point to a file/folder that doesn't exist?
RewriteCond  /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/fswtest%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/fswtest%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Is there a folder in the URL? Get the first one in the list.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([^\/]+)\/
# Remove JUST THE FIRST FOLDER from the REQUEST_URI and start again
RewriteRule .\/(.*) /$1?folder[]=%1 [N,QSA]
```

My regex works great, and it removes 1 folder per loop starting at the left as long as the folder doesn't exist until all that's left is the correct folder (I checked the logs to make sure it was doing this and indeed it matches each folder each time), however, browsing to http://example.org/this/folder/isnt/real/whatever.php I expected $_GET['folder'] to be an array of ['this','folder','isnt','real'] however for some reason the array just contains ['this','this','this','this'] as for some reason the %1 variable isn't updating on each subsequent [N] loop.

Why would %1 be equal to 'this' on runs where the word 'this' isn't even in the URI anymore due to being removed on a previous run?

I tried browsing to http://example.org/this/folder/isnt/real/whatever.php.

I expected be redirected to "http://example.org/whatever.php" with $_GET['folder'] = ['this','folder','isnt','real']
Instead I got redirected to "http://example.org/whatever.php" with $_GET['folder'] = ['this','this','this','this']

Comment: Any difference if you use the `L` flag instead of the `N`?

Comment: Well, yeah I mean if you use L it just removes whatever the first "fake" folder is and then ends the job, sending the URI to the server and the server says "file not found" because it didn't loop through the other folders to remove them.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you had this configured via .htaccess or on the directory level, but if that's not the case, then `L` behaves differently.

Comment: If you changed it to `?folder[]=%{REQUEST_URI}`, then I assume it would give you four times the same value as well?

Comment: That would give me the URI. I need to know a list of fake folders that have been popped off the URI.

Comment: I know, I wanted you to do this to help _debug_ the issue ... Sounds like `%{REQUEST_URI}` does _not_ get updated in between multiple applications of the rule, and this would be a way to verify that.

Comment: Good catch! Yes, you're right, it not updating on each [N] loop!

Comment: Can you try and capture the necessary values via the RewriteRule instead? Something like `RewriteRule /([^/]+)/(.+) /$2?folder[]=$1 [N,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that %{REQUEST_URI} doesn't actually get updated when you use [N] to loop back to the start with an updated Request so any matches against %{REQUEST_URI} wont take into account changes to the Request that have been made. If there is any way to perform matches against a Request that has been modified using RewriteRule, I don't know of them.

In the end I had to just take the entire URI into the query string and operate on the information from a different approach.